# Get next Friday and next 2nd monday

Tags: vb.net, datetime

starting from today date (ex. friday 10/07/2020) i have to get next friday date (17/07/2020), so the output shouldn't be the today date.

I also have to take the next 2nd monday starting from today date (ex. friday 10/07/2020) and the output should be 20/07/2020.

How can I reach this in VBNet?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You need to make some sort of effort before asking us to step in. We're not here so that you don't have to bother trying for yourself. We're here for the stuff you tried but failed and, if that's what has already happened, then you need to show us what you did and tell us what happened. If you have bothered reading about the `DateTime` type then you know all the members it has so you already have all the information you need to solve the problem yourself. Make that effort and come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: i tried in many ways, but i'm also very "noob" at developing, and i still can't understand many things... I usually "study" a working code and then use it, i think it's a way to learn

Comment: It is "a" way to learn but there's far more to learning than just that. Examples help but it's very easy to see an example, think you know what's going on but then not be able to write your own code for any situation even slightly different. If you want to take the lazy way then that's your prerogative but SO is not the place to get people to write examples from scratch. Here, you're expected to make your best attempt and, if that doesn't work, show us what you did and explain why you did it and what happened when you did it. Do that and plenty of people will help you fix what's broken.

Comment: The way to approach any programming problem is to start by forgetting that it's a programming problem. Think about how you would approach it if you had to do it manually, with pen and paper. Break it down into smaller and smaller steps and formalise them into an algorithm that you can follow the get the right result every time. Only then should you consider writing code and the code should directly implement the algorithm. The greener you are, the more important it is to stick to this approach. As you get more experienced, you can safely start to take shortcuts, not the other way around.

Comment: Don't know how to say this, but I tried in so many way. I also searched many topics on google but no one has an answer or, atleast, not a consistent solution. Your way of "talking" looks really inappropriate, all this moral comments for what? Didn't know this site was a school where "profs" blame you instead of giving some advice that can help someone to reach the solution. Anyway, thanks for your non-help. If u can clear look my profile you can see I only open a thread when i'm totally out of idea.

Comment: Please show us the many ways that you tried. Then we can more easily help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to say to you:

> You are on step 10, I want you to jump forward to step 17, and then jump forward to step 20. What are the size of your jumps?

What would you do?

```
17 - 10 = 7
20 - 17 = 3
```

Now if I said

> You are on some random step between 10 and 16. What is the process?

17 - whatever ..

So you're solving this problem with math

---

[DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1) can tell you/do for you a couple of things:

- The current date, [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netcore-3.1)
- The current [day of the week](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1) as an enumeration from 0 (sunday) to 6 (saturday)
- What the date is if you [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.add?view=netcore-3.1) some number of days to it

So if you say :

```
Dim dayNumber = DirectCast(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek, Integer)
```

For today it will give you 4. How far until the next 6? 2

If you say:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
```

For today, that will be Friday. If you wanted it to be the friday *after* the friday in 2 days, you could `AddDays(7+2)` etc. You can guess how to get to the Monday after these...

(It helps to see dates as just a number. Every time you add 1, you go up by a day. If you add 0.5 days you go up by 12 hours etc.. You can increment datetimes just like you would numbers and at any time you can ask "what day is this?")

And then all you have to do is print out the times you found

---

Note that `DateTime.Now` includes the time too; you can only really work with it and get rid of it when you print out. There is a `.Date` property that gives you a datetime with the time set to midnight but a DateTime will always have a timel you just "don't show it" if you don't need it, by doing e.g. `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to get a string representation of the date, without the time

---

I've linked the doumentation; you can find in depth examples there. To change the presentation of the examples to VB use the # button in the top right

Comment: Finally a non-useless comment. Thanks for the help, I gonna try to find out how to solve my problem now! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Give these a go:

```
Public Function GetFridaySkippingToday(today As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim result = today.AddDays(1.0)
    While result.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Friday
        result = result.AddDays(1.0)
    End While
    Return result
End Function

Public Function GetDayOfWeek(today As DateTime, dayOfWeek As DayOfWeek, skip As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim result = today
    While True
        If result.DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek Then
            If skip = 0 Then
                Exit While
            Else
                skip -= 1
            End If
        End If
        result = result.AddDays(1.0)
    End While
    Return result
End Function
```